# Como adicionar uma biblioteca num projeto, de modo que ele rode em outros computadores?

Tags: java, github, netbeans, library, ant

Estou fazendo um projeto em java (com Ant) no netbeans e usando uma biblioteca. Roda tranquilo na minha máquina, mas quando outros fazem um pull em meu projeto do github, ele apresenta erros devido a ausência do .jar da biblioteca usada. Há alguma forma de adicionar a biblioteca ao projeto no repositório? Ou então fazer um script para que o  .jar seja baixado nas dependências? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: dá uma pesquisada sobre maven ou graddle, que são gerenciadores de dependências que resolvem esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Procura usar algum gerenciador de dependências como o Maven ou Graddle, ou remove do arquivo **.gitignore** dentro do seu repositório, a linha referente à arquivos **.jar**, assim você sobe o mesmo no git e a pessoa só atualiza a versão da máquina dela dando um pull na sua branch.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).